# Нормализация HTML/CSS/JS файлов.

Tags: html, css, javascript

Все доброго времени суток.

Как быстрей всего причесать html/css/js? Сервис или мод на Sublime-text, которые быстро удалят все не нужные пробелы между соседними блочными тегами и сделают грамотные отступы вложенности кода.

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инструменты для форматирования CSS-кода:

- Styleneat  http://www.styleneat.com/
- FormatCSS http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/
- CleanCSS http://www.cleancss.com/
- ProCSSor http://procssor.com/
- CSScomb http://csscomb.ru/
- Code Beautifier http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Инструменты для форматирования HTML-кода:

- XHTML formatter http://extranet.pseltd.com/xhtml_formatter.aspx
- HTML Tidy http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy

Также почитайте об этом:

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/154667/
- http://blog.of-it.org/ru/post/osnovnye-plaginy-i-rasshireniya-dlya-sublime-text-2

Comment: Спасибо за подборку

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь сторонним сервисом http://cssbeautify.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем недавно искал и нашел такие он-лайн сервисы для минификации CSS и JS

http://www.minifyjs.com/

http://javascript-minifier.com/